# How can put an event on a QButtonGroup button in c++?

Tags: c++, qt, events

My buttonGroup is already load with 45 buttons i want do anything after a button is clicked this is my code:

```
#include "escogerpuesto.h"
#include "ui_escogerpuesto.h"
#include <iostream>

EscogerPuesto::EscogerPuesto(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::EscogerPuesto)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->buttonGroup->connect(ui->buttonGroup, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(asientoClickeado));
}

EscogerPuesto::~EscogerPuesto()
{
    delete ui;
}

void EscogerPuesto::asientoClickeado()
{
    std::cout<<"click en asiento";
}
```

Comment: There's no clicked() signal in QButtonGroup, have a look at the documentation. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qbuttongroup.html There's e.g. buttonClicked(int), if that's what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Button group contains signal with parameter QAbstractButton* or int, so you should connect this signal with slot which has an appropriate parameter.

```
    ui->buttonGroup->connect(ui->buttonGroup, SIGNAL(buttonClicked(QAbstractButton*)),
                             this, SLOT(your_slot(QAbstractButton* ));
```

Or you can connect each button with some slot.

You can read more here: http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/signalsandslots.html

and here http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qbuttongroup.html

Comment: There's way that i can know which button is clicked??

Comment: @user3050498, Yes, it is sent as parameter (pointer to it) in your slot. See `buttonClicked ( QAbstractButton * button )` in QButtonGroup